# Will Windows 10 Wake/Turn on to install/download updates when in shutdown

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, sleep, shutdown

If you shutdown your PC will windows 10 wake or turn on to install updates that were already downloaded previously? As well as turn on to download and install new updates?

Second, how do you turn this feature off for both shutdown and sleep mode as I keep my laptop in a bag and do not want it to turn on and do this type of behavior.

Comment: If you specifically turn your machine off, then Windows is unable to update, due to the fact it's turned off.  If your machine is specifically put into S3 mode, then Windows again, will not install updates.  **However, S3 mode means the machine is still turned on, you should use Suspend instead which turns the machine off.**

Comment: @Ramhound I am not sure what S3 is and how to use suspend?

Comment: S3 is sleep mode.  However, Windows still does not come out of sleep mode, to install updates.  S3 is just the wrong mode if you are putting a device in a bag, since the machine is actually turned on, just in a very low power state.

Answer (score 0):

Windows will never turn on from shutdown mode or sleep to install updates.

Comment: @ Ricardo I have tested it and my laptop has woken up to install updates

Comment: @LukeF - Which is the reason you should use suspend not sleep mode, sleep mode means your machine is still turned on, which means your battery is slowly draining.

Comment: Maybe it woke up because it was squeezed or shaken around in your bag an thus maybe some key must have been pressed or something

Comment: I think if you Allow Wake Timers to wake for important timers from sleep/suspend that you can have the machine awake to do updates.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is not valid in my case. I have Ubuntu / Windows 10 dual boot (Ubuntu being default).

Every time an update is pending and I put the laptop to sleep I come back seeing Ubuntu in front of me.

Should Ubuntu has not been the default OS Windows would've restarted, install updates, put it back to sleep, and I as a Windows user wouldn't even know. It preserves the state of opened chrome instances.

Maybe it happens during inactivity hours and for small updates (not major OS version upgrades) and when the laptop is plugged in as well.